# How do you use memcached (not memcache) with PHP (part 2)

Tags: php, caching, memcached

On the first page, I have this

```
// start memcached
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$key = 'test_' . $ID_ref;
$test_data = array(....);
$m->set($key, $test_data);
// end memcached
```

OK, so far. On the next page,

```
// start memcached
$m = new Memcached();
$m->connect('localhost', 11211);
var_dump($m->get($key));
// end memcached
```

The following error occured:

> Call to undefined method Memcached::connect()

`phpinfo()` shows that memcached is installed by webhost, and it seems that [memcached does not support](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)  `connect()`

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->connect('localhost', 11211);
```

simply re-use

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
```

`connect()` is a *Memcache* method and not *Memcached*

Comment: I got this output

    bool(false) 

What does it mean?

Comment: Just ensure your `$key` values are the same on both `set()` and `get()` calls. If you wish to test it's working OK you can perform a set and a get after each other in the same script.

Comment: they are the same, I've set both to $key = 'test_1'; for both with the same result

Comment: It is bool(false) also on the same script.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to help you with sorry, memcached really is a simple little beastie, you can try getting a memcache admin panel to check that you're successfully storing keys. eg https://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/